# Monitor doesnt work after login notebook amd ATI

Tags: 16.04, drivers, multiple-monitors, hdmi, amd-graphics

I have ubuntu 16.04 from some time my monitor (samsung s24d33) stopped cooperate with my notebook (ideapad 320)

My PC with same ubuntu (geforce) works with the same cable and monitor.
My TV works with both (PC and Notebook) - still the same cable.
Other cables - same problem.

The problem is when I connect hdmi to Samsung monitor and run notebook I can see loading screen atc but when it's fully loaded monitor turns black. It looks like it's connected but nothing happen. I also see it in screen settings and I can change resolution for it - but still black.

Did anyone have problem like this and found solution?

> sudo lshw -C video

```
  *-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 1
   bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
   version: da
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
   resources: irq:227 memory:e0000000-e7ffffff memory:e8000000-e87fffff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:e8e00000-e8e3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

> grep -i chipset /var/log/Xorg.0.log

```
[     8.369] (II) AMDGPU: Driver for AMD Radeon chipsets: BONAIRE, BONAIRE, BONAIRE,
[     8.369] (II) RADEON: Driver for ATI Radeon chipsets:
[     8.373] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[     8.374] (--) AMDGPU(0): Chipset: "STONEY" (ChipID = 0x98e4)
```

> AMD A9-9420 RADEON R5, 5 COMPUTE CORES 2C+3G × 2
>   AMD STONEY (DRM
>   3.18.0 / 4.13.0-41-generic, LLVM 5.0.0)

Comment: updated to 18.04 and now it works